# Can't upgrade the system and unable to install/remove and open applications and this issue is in ubuntu20. 04LTS version

Tags: package-management, error-handling

I am a new Linux user and I cannot upgrade the system and install/remove and open applications. I get the following error:

[image: update error]

I have tried `apt --fix broken install`, "repaired broken packages from recovery mode".

For `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://ny-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ny-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ny-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ny-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

For `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatomic1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libbsd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not installed
 libcrypt1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not installed
 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installed
 libdrm-intel1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installed
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libdrm2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installed
 libedit2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installed
 libelf1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installed
 libexpat1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not installed
 libffi7:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libgcc-s1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not installed
 libgl1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installed
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libglvnd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libglx-mesa0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installed
 libglx0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libidn2-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libllvm11:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installed
 libnvidia-compute-460:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libnvidia-decode-460:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libnvidia-encode-460:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installed
 libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libnvidia-gl-460:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not installed
 libpciaccess0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libsensors5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not installed
 libtinfo6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.16) but it is not installed
 libunistring2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 libvulkan1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installed
 libwayland-client0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installed
 libx11-6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installed
 libxau6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxcb-glx0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxcb-present0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxcb-randr0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxcb-sync1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxcb1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installed
 libxdamage1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxdmcp6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxext6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxfixes3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libxshmfence1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libxxf86vm1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 libzstd1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installed
 zlib1g:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: updated the question!!!

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: Welcome, please add the output of `grep -Rn --include=\*.list ^[^\#] /etc/apt/` and `uname -a`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: It's probably a typo in your question, but `--fix-broken` is a single argument with a dash in it, not a space. You may also want to try `sudo apt-get full-upgrade`. It does look like you may be missing some repositories, so be sure to check out the link @N0rbert provided.